# How to apply style on a window in Xaml

Tags: wpf

I tried to apply style on a window in Xaml. But my code is not applying the style. Can anyone help me out in this problem?

```
<Window x:Class="Shweta.Window5"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Window5" Height="300" Width="300">

    <Window.Resources>
        <Style  TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Verdana"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="LightBlue"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="WindowStyle" Value="None"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightBlue"></Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="40*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="238*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="47*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="214*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid Grid.Column="1">
            <Button Margin="0,0,114,16" Content="shweta"/>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of putting the Style into the Window's `Resources`, you could directly assign it to the `Style` property of the Window:

```
<Window x:Class="Shweta.Window5"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Window5" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Window.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Verdana"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="LightBlue"/>
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal"/>
            <Setter Property="WindowStyle" Value="None"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightBlue"/>
        </Style>
    </Window.Style>
    ...
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to put your style in the `Resources` of your App.xaml.

```
<Application.Resources>
    <Style  TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
        <Setter Property="FontFamily"
                Value="Verdana"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Foreground"
                Value="LightBlue"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="FontWeight"
                Value="Normal"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="WindowStyle"
                Value="None"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Background"
                Value="LightBlue"></Setter>
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

When you define your `Style` in the `Window` it'll be for the children of the `Window` but not the `Window` itself.

Comment: Yes, I tried with <application.resources> , it applied the style to all the pages in the entire project. Thanks !